# Swiper.js loop when slidesPerView is bigger than half of the amount of Slides

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

As it seems since version 9 of swiper.js you cannot loop through your slides if you do not have more than double the slides available than slidesPerView. So for example if I want to build a slider that shows 5 products at once, and want to loop through a list of 7 products I cannot do that. If I show just 1 or 2 products at once everything is fine.

This behavior seems to come from the new loop logic they implemented. Here is my configuration for the swiper:

```js
const params = 
            modules: [Autoplay, Pagination, Navigation],
            autoplay: {
                enabled: false,
                speed: 3000,
            },
            speed: 400,
            navigation: true,
            pagination:{
                enabled: true,
                dynamicBullets: true,
                dynamicMainBullets: 4
            },
            loop: true,
            spaceBetween: 30,
            centeredSlides: false,
            breakpoints: {
                0: {
                    slidesPerView: 1,
                },
                [BREAKPOINT_WIDTH.extraSmall*16]: {
                    slidesPerView: 3
                },
                [BREAKPOINT_WIDTH.medium*16]: {
                    slidesPerView: 3
                },
                [BREAKPOINT_WIDTH.large*16]: {
                    slidesPerView: 5
                }
            },
        };
```

Is there an option I overlooked? Or has somebody a solution for the problem?

---

EDIT: As of v11 of Swiperjs this is fixed and it works again.

Comment: Experiencing same issue where slidesPerView: 3 and only 4 slides rendered. Tested on version 8 with no problems. I'll submit a bug report.

Comment: @James0r Could you please link the bug report to your comment ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, from the v9 the loop isn't working anymore, as you mention and as explained on their [documentation](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-loop)

> Because of nature of how the loop mode works (it will rearrange slides), total number of slides must be >= slidesPerView * 2

So sadly for now you have no option than dirty work arround.

1. Stay on swiper v8
2. Increase your total number of slides by duplicating the rendered item *Poor solution*

```js
if(slidesPerView * 2 < items?.length) items = items.concat(items)
```

3. Put a limit on your slidesPerView to adapt himself to how many items you'll be rendering

```js
const slidesPerView = items.length >= slidesPerView * 2 ? slidesPerView : Math.floor(items.length / 2)
```

*Note: I saw that even if you respect the number, if you add `autoHeight: true` it wont be working properly*

### Note

*I've already open an [issue](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/6600#event-10232341511) in the swiper.js Github repo, but this went closed as not planned, so we'll have to live with it :/*

Comment: I cloned items as in 2 and it worked fine, but I agree solution is subpar.

Comment: Any new solution for this?
I have total 7 slides and slidesPerView is 6. In loop mode, its completely broken functionality

Comment: @KiranLala No sorry, I'll update my answer as soon as swiper.js does an update.

Comment: @KiranLala They have closed [my feature request](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/6600#event-10232341511), so I think this will be the way to do for the next couple of month/year :/

Answer (score 2):

This has finally been fixed in v11, as mentioned in the [changelog](https://swiperjs.com/changelog#1100-2023-09-24). If anyone's still facing this issue, they should upgrade to v11.

Answer (score 0):

Updating of Swipe to v11 is helped me. I had issue with scrolling when slidesPerView > 1